# How to use AWK command via Ansible

Tags: shell, awk, ansible

I have a problem with creating ansible role.

I want to register variable via Ansible using awk in shell module.

It work when i use it via terminal like that:

```
inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d"(" -f2
```

But when I want to use it in Ansible role it doesnt work.

```
name: Get info
shell: inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d"(" -f2
register: result
```

Displayed info from
`inxi -D` is

```
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 53.7GB (2.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/vda model: N/A size: 53.7GB
           ID-2: /dev/vdb model: N/A size: 0.0GB
```

And I want to extract data about usage fo HDD e.g. 2.0%

Can someone help with that?

Comment: what output you got for `inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d"(" -f2` ?

Comment: 2.0% from line  `Drives:    HDD Total Size: 53.7GB (2.0% used)  `
            `ID-1: /dev/vda model: N/A size: 53.7GB ` 
            ` ID-2: /dev/vdb model: N/A size: 0.0GB  `

Comment: Can you add the output of just `inxi -D` to your question, so that it (1) retains proper formatting and (2) allows us to suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: `echo $(command)` is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and should simply be `command`.

Comment: @ghoti I have add info

Comment: Not sure if this is the same problem, but I was trying to run a `shell` command and I just had to escape the `\$`.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: test shell
    shell: >
      echo "Drives:    HDD Total Size: 53.7GB (2.0% used)" | awk -F '[()]' '/Total Size:/ {split($2,a," "); print a[1]}'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

It should print something like:

```
"msg": "2.0%"
```

If working then just replace the `echo ...` with your command: `inxi -D | awk ...`

Notice the `shell: >`

In `yaml`, Multiple-line strings can be written either as a 'literal block' (using `|`), or a 'folded block' (using `>`).

Also changed the use of awk to use all in one by using `[()]` as the separator, this will get contents within parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

This way it works fine

```
 - name: Get informations about disk percentage
      shell: >
                inxi -D |
                grep 'Total'|
                sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\)\ .*/\1/'
      register: result

- debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

Comment: That `grep` is entirely unnecessary; the same filtering can be done in sed alone. What about just `inxi -D | sed -ne '/^Drives/{s/.*(//;s/ .*//;p;q;}'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute as below:

```
 name: Get info
 shell: inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d"(" -f2
 register: result
```

and access the output of that command by `"{{ result.stdout }}"`

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt work. `changed: [168.99.241.225] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d\"(\" -f2", "delta": "0:00:00.197516", "end": "2018-05-20 17:38:12.433230", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-05-20 17:38:12.235714", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Answer (score 0):

inxi as of version 3.0 exports to json or xml:

```
inxi -Dxxx --output json --output-file print
```

'print' is print to stdout, if a full file path is given, it exports to the file.

Answer (score 0):

we just find a stupid workaround that work:

```
echo $(df -h /hadoop | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')
```

for the first case :

```
      tasks:
      - name: test shell
        shell: echo $(inxi -D | awk '/Total Size:/ {print $7}' | cut -d"(" -f2)
        register: result
```