Command runs manually but fails with ansible
I have a file /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env with the below contents:
export EF_OID=AP0084
export EF_PWD=mypass1

export OID=ap0085
export PWD=mypass2
export FDPWD=mypass2
export AP0085_PWD=mypass2
export SVR=AFFPROD
export TWO_TASK=db01

Given the userid ap0085 The below command on solaris give me the password for that userid:
$ nawk 'tolower($0) ~ /\=ap0085/ {getline; print}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}'
Output:
mypass2

Snapshot:

I wanted to try the same in ansible and tried both the raw: and shell: modules.
While the raw module errored the shell module did not grab anything in the output.
Ansible play:
   - name: Debug Search for the password
     debug: 
       msg: "nawk 'tolower($0) ~ /\\={{ executeuser }}/ {getline; print}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}'"

   - name: Search for the password
     shell: "nawk 'tolower($0) ~ /\\={{ executeuser }}/ {getline; print}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}'"
     become: true
     become_user: "{{ copyuserondest }}"   
     ignore_errors: true
     register: passfound
  

   - debug:
       msg: "pass found: {{ passfound.stdout }}"

Output:
TASK [Debug Search for the password] *******************************************
ok: [remotehost] => {
    "msg": "nawk 'tolower($0) ~ /\\\\=ap0085/ {getline; print}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}'"
}

TASK [Search for the password] *************************************************
changed: [remotehost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [remotehost] => {
    "msg": "pass found: "
}

As you can see the password found is empty.
I tried another solution by SO user U880D but it errors.
Note: the password will be on the next immediate line of the found search pattern i.e ap0085
PLAYBOOK:
- set_fact:
    executeuser: ap0085

- slurp:
    src: /tmp/.unx_env
  register: unix_env

- debug:
    msg: "{{ unix_env.content | b64decode }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ unix_env.content | b64decode | regex_search(executeuser ~ 'PWD=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"                                                                                                            

Output with error:
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 19 April 2024  07:47:39 -0500 (0:00:00.018)       0:00:00.753 **********
ok: [remotehost] => {
    "msg": "export EF_OID=AP0084\nexport EF_PWD=mypass1\n\nexport OID=ap0085\nexport PWD=mypass2\nexport FDPWD=mypass2\nexport AP0085_PWD=mypass2\nexport SVR=AFFPROD\nexport TWO_TASK=db01\n"
}

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 19 April 2024  07:47:39 -0500 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:00.788 **********
fatal: [remotehost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ unix_env.content | b64decode | regex_search(executeuser ~ 'PWD=(.+)', '\\\\1') | first }}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable"} 

Can you please suggest how to escape get the same manual command to work in ansible please?

I had no issues using awk 'tolower($0) ~ /=ap0085/ {getline; print}' .unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}' for the shell command in my playbook. I did not use quotes around it.

For the given file a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    USERID: AP0085

  tasks:

  - slurp:
      src: unix.env
    register: unix_env

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ unix_env.content | b64decode | regex_search(USERID ~ '_PWD=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: mypass2

This approach can be adopted, changed or enhanced to the specific needs.
Thanks To

Extracting part of the string using Ansible regex_search and save the output as a variable


An other less recommended approach could be to use grep.
  - shell:
      cmd: "grep '{{ USERID }}_PWD=' unix.env | cut -d '=' -f 2"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

resulting into the same output.
Further Reading

grep usage on Solaris
grep syntax in Solaris
Searching for Patterns With grep


i m getting the following error executing your answer: Play: - set_fact: newpassfound: "{{ unix_env.content | b64decode | regex_search(executeuser ~ '_PWD=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}" Output: TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************** fatal: [remotehost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ unix_env.content | b64decode | regex_search(executeuser ~ '_PWD=(.+)', '\\1') | first }}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable"}

As one can see from the minimal reproducible answer, there is no such issue. Regarding 'NoneType' object is not iterable is your variable unix_env.content just empty? Without much much more detail it is impossible to follow up on this comment for me.

Regarding:
nawk 'tolower($0) ~ /\=ap0085/ {getline; print}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env | awk -F= '{print $2}'


You don't need to (and so must not for portability) escape = in a regexp, it's not a metachar. Just do /=ap0085/, not /\=ap0085/. Escaping a char that's not a metachar is undefined behavior so any tool can do whatever it likes with that and still be POSIX compliant. Given that you don't need \\ or \\\\ either but even if you did, don't keep piling on backslashes, use [x] instead of \\x or \\\\x to make x literal if/when you have to.
You never need to pipe awk to another call to awk, the above is equivalent to:

nawk -F= 'tolower($0) ~ /\=ap0085/ {getline; print $2}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env


You're calling nawk in your first script but then piping it to awk. I can't imagine why you'd decide to change awk variants in a pipeline but with awk instead of nawk you'll probably pick up the default awk on Solaris which is old, broken awk which must never be used by anyone for any purpose, see http://awk.freeshell.org/oawk.
The awk variants in /usr/xpg*/bin (xpg4 and xpg6) are closer to POSIX compliant than nawk and so should be used instead.
Use of getline is generally to be avoided except in very specific circumstances and this isn't one of them, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.
Your regexp isn't bounded (/=ap0085$/) and so it's open to a false match if ap00859 or some other value that ap0085 is a substring of exists in the context you're interested in matching on.
You aren't testing for OID= and so =ap0085 could match anywhere instead of just the line you want it to match on.
You aren't testing for PASS= and so if the input was in a different order you'd get output that isn't the password you want.

If you wanted to do this more robustly in awk in the same style as you are using then it'd be (use gawk or /usr/xpg6/bin/awk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk as you like but do not use /usr/bin/awk on Solaris):
$ awk -F= '
    toupper($0) ~ /^[^=]+OID=AP0085$/ { f=1 }
    f && sub(/^[^=]+PWD=/,"") { print; exit }
' file
mypass2

but it'd take a different approach, a better understanding of your requirements, and quite a bit more code to make it totally robust (e.g. to handle the case where OID comes after PWD instead of before it in the input or there are other variables that end in OID or PWD you do not want to match, etc.).
I'm not very familiar with ansible but I googled "how to call awk from ansible" and the first hit is the SO question How to use AWK command via Ansible which seems to contain answers to that question, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/50438327/1745001 which shows:
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: test shell
    shell: >
      echo "Drives:    HDD Total Size: 53.7GB (2.0% used)" | awk -F '[()]' '/Total Size:/ {split($2,a," "); print a[1]}'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

So if I modify some of your ansible code to do what it shows there that would be:
- name: Debug Search for the password
  shell: >
    awk -F'=' '
        toupper($0) ~ /^[^=]+OID=AP0085$/ { f=1 }
        f && sub(/^[^=]+PWD=/,"") { print; exit }
    ' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env
 register: result

- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

Hopefully that finds the password and you can do whatever else you need to do given that starting point.

Although your suggestion helps better the command making it concise and returns proper output when run manually  can you help with how can i incorporate the command in ansible shell: ? `nawk -F= 'tolower($0) ~ /={{ executeuser}}/ {getline; print $2}' /u/mybank/UNX/config/.unx_env
As my ansible play is failing with syntax error.
`

@Ashar sorry, I don't know what ansibles rules are for calling shell/awk but I did suggest you get rid of the \ as a starting point. Beyond that, I expect googling "how to call awk from ansible" or similar will quickly show you what you need to do.

I just googled "how to call awk from ansible" and the first hit is the SO question how-to-use-awk-command-via-ansible which seems to contain answers to that question but there's a ton of other hits too if it doesn't.

/=ap0085/ command does not even work manually on Solaris so I cannot use your suggestion ... the command only works when we use /\=ap0085/ however, I m still clueless about how to get it to work using ansible.

@Ashar then you're doing something else wrong (maybe missing a quote somewhere in the calling code? idk) and putting that \ before the = is hiding the real problem instead of fixing it as you should not escape = in a regexp or you're introducing undefined behavior which makes the \ useless at best and will silently cause your script to produce incorrect output at worst.

FWIW I see you're enclosing your shell script in double quotes - shell: "nawk '...'", I don't see anything in the answers to the question I googled suggesting you should do that (and if you were doing this from shell rather than ansible that'd be breaking the script, idk about from ansible) so maybe that's the real problem?

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50438327/1745001 to the first google result seems like it shows exactly how to do what you're asking about. I update my answer to show that approach from that answer applied to at least part of your problem.
